# TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined - Mapping Data onto Card and rendering onto menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, array.prototype.map

I am trying to map data into my Material Ui card component that is then rendered onto a grid for a food menu, and from clicking the buttons above you switch menus.

I am following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGaaw1Py2aY&list=PLVwSdwIkTF50m5Fnd-_vSIrT8mvtfeZxe&index=13) although I am trying to do a more complex version as I am mapping the data into a card then rendering separate cards onto a menu grid.

However I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" and am trying to get my head round whether the way I am doing it is the wrong approach or I have just made a mistake I cannot find.

Link to code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/f1807647089)

Notes:

1. The error is in the MenuCard.js file.
2. It is being designed mobile first so if you pop into view for mobile screen UI will be more usable etc.... not built the tablet or desktop UI yet
3. click order now button and will take you to menupage where error is

also code below...
MenuCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    ["@media (max-width: 460px"]:{
        maxWidth: "150px",
        maxHeight: "250px",
    }
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
});

export default function MenuCard({ data, cardIndex}) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      {data[cardIndex].map(item => (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={item.image}
                title="Contemplative Reptile"
              />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                {item.header}
              </Typography>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                {item.price}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
          <CardActions>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
              Info
            </Button>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
              Order
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

MenuPage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Container, Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Section } from './LandingPage'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { AddCartButton, InformationButton } from '../Components/MaterialIconButton'
import MenuCard from '../Components/Menu/MenuCard'
import { MobileFoodMenu } from '../Components/Menu/MobileFoodMenu'
import {MenuData} from '../Data/MenuData'

export const MenuPage = () => {

    const [active, setActive] = useState("FirstMenu");

    return (
        <div style={{height: "100vh"}}>
            <Container style={{height: "100%"}}>
                <Grid container>
                    <Section>
                        <MenuHeader>
                            <ContentSection>
                                <button onClick={()  => setActive("FirstMenu")}>Starters</button>
                                <button onClick={()  => setActive("SecondMenu")}>Mains</button>
                                <button onClick={()  => setActive("ThirdMenu")}>Sundries</button>
                                <button onClick={()  => setActive("FourthMenu")}>Desserts</button>
           
                            </ContentSection>
                        </MenuHeader>
                        <MenuContainer>
                            {active === "FirstMenu" && <MobileFoodMenu data={MenuData} menuIndex={0}/>}
                            {active === "SecondMenu" && <MobileFoodMenu data={MenuData} menuIndex={1}/>}
                            {active === "ThirdMenu" && <MobileFoodMenu data={MenuData} menuIndex={2} />}
                            {active === "FourthMenu" && <MobileFoodMenu data={MenuData} menuIndex={3}/>}
                        </MenuContainer>



        
                    </Section>  
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

const MenuHeader = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #628395;
    /* top: 15%; */
    top: 15%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
    z-index: 100;
`
const ContentSection = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; 
    padding: 5%;
    /* background-color: black; */

`
const MenuContainer = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20%;


`
const CardContainer = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    height: 275px;
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 1px rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.2);
    background-color: #f4f4f4;

`
const CardImageHolder = styled.div`
    height: 50%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
    /* background-color: black; */
`
const CardTitle = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100%;
    
   
`
const InfoButtonDiv = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 110%;
`
const BasketButtonDiv = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 135%;
`
const InfoButton = styled.button`
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
   
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 130%;
`
const OrderButton = styled.button`
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
   
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;

    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 150%;

    background-color: #185ADB;
`
```

Comment: Ivar Everyone normally comments having a go at me to provide a code sandbox and tha'ts what the link links too.... if you follow the link all the code files are in there (click order now button to go to error) - but I will edit the post and put a code formatted now gimme 2 mins :)

Comment: You can tell those who tell you that, that they are wrong. A supplementary link that demo's your problem is welcome, but all the code necessary to answer the question should be in the question itself. See ["_Questions seeking debugging help ... must include ... in the question itself_"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I agree Ivar I use to put them in but thought codepen-sandbox etc was the norm now! will keep putting them in from now on thanks

Comment: `MenuCard` wants `data` and `cardIndex` props. If you don't pass these props you will get the error.

Comment: thanks for input Giovanni - I thought I was doing this though by destructuring it in object of the function (sorry if terminology is wrong) - MenuCard({data, cardIndex}){} is where I tried doing that in MenuCard.js. By passing props do you mean as in use props.item etc?

Comment: @MicSt Yes I mean you have to write something like: `<MenuCard data={yuorData} cardIndex={yourcardIndex}/>`

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Okay I get what you mean I think I am going wrong because I think potentially I am passing data into my <MobileFoodMenu/> before the card component potentially